# combine equal pairs into equivalence classes

Tags: algorithms, equivalence-relations, clustering

Given a set $S$ of values, and a set $P \subset S \times S$ of pairwise equivalences, what is an algorithm for partitioning $S$ into equivalence classes?
$P$ is guaranteed to be an equivalence relation.
Assume that $P$ "covers" every member of $S$.
Efficiency isn't all that crucial:  I'm interested in $\#S < 100000$ and $\#P < 10000$.

This is like building up pairs into clusters, but because this is for exact equality rather than mere similarity, I'm finding that clustering algorithms are red herrings.

Comment: Is $P$ guaranteed to be an equivalence relation (for example, is it transitive)? If so, then one can start with any $s\in S$ and then add anything related to $s$, then anything related to those new things, and so on recursive—that will result in the equivalence class of $s$.

Comment: Yes (edited to clarify).  I'm just not sure whether to iterate on $P$ or on $S$ until it's exhausted, or to recurse on a growing set of clusters, or what.  Intuitively, "just agglomerate."

Comment: Equivalence classes on the set $S$ are the same as the connected component of the graph whose edges are given by $P$. https://www.baeldung.com/cs/graph-connected-components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalence classes on the set $S$ are the same as the connected components of the graph whose edges are given by $P$. Fortunately, there are standard algorithms for computing the connected components: [here is one example](http://baeldung.com/cs/graph-connected-components).